# Does the newton method with $f(x)=x^p$ converge superlinearly?

Tags: newton-raphson, rate-of-convergence

Let $f(x)=x^p$ with $p>2$. The steps for the newton method are known as $x_{k+1}=x_k+d_k$ and $d_k = -\frac{\nabla f(x_k)}{\nabla^2 f(x_k)}$

I want to check if the Newton method converges superlinearly for this case.

---

It'd converges superlinearly (according to lecture) if $$\|x_{k+1}-\bar{x}\| \leq \epsilon_k \|x_k-\bar{x}\|$$
where $\{\epsilon_k\}_k \rightarrow 0$ and $\bar{x}$ is a stationary point.

Obviously, the stationary point of $f(x)=x^p$ is at $x=0$. So I thought I should prove...
$$\frac{\|x_{k+1}\|}{\|x_{k}\|}\leq \epsilon_k \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow \frac{\|x_{k+1}\|}{\|x_{k}\|}\rightarrow 0$$

This is not the case, because...
$$\frac{\|x_{k+1}\|}{\|x_{k}\|} = \frac{\|x_{k}+d_k\|}{\|x_{k}\|} = \frac{\|x_{k}-\frac{\nabla f(x_k)}{\nabla^2 f(x_k)}\|}{\|x_{k}\|}=\frac{\|x_{k}-\frac{px_k^{p-1}}{p(p-1)x_k^{p-2}}\|}{\|x_{k}\|}=\frac{\|(1-\frac{1}{p-1})x_{k}\|}{\|x_{k}\|}=|(1-\frac{1}{p-1})| \nrightarrow 0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I am very surprised by your definition of the Newton method : for a derivable function $f$ defined on an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, the recursion formula is $$x_{k+1} := x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}.$$ When $f(x)=x^p$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$, where $p>1$ is fixed, you get a geometric sequence. More generally, Newton method does not work well to approach a zero of $f$ when the differential of $f$ ar this zero is singular.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I'm probably using something similar to this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization

Comment: Ah, you apply Newton method to search for the critical points of $f$, namely the zeroes of $f'$. That is why you assume that $p>2$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Yes that's correct. Sorry that my question didn't make that clear - there are a few definitions flying around when talking about Newton method.

Comment: Anyway, you get a geometric sequence when applying the method to the function $x \mapsto x^p$.